# how to open a mongodb database when only the dbpath is available?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

That might be a very silly question, but how can I open a mongodb database?

Here is the setup: I have another computer where a bmongo database is continuously feeded by some python program (using pymongo). The dbpath of the mongodb database is on dropbox, so that I can access the data while on the go.

Problem: How can I open these data on my machine? I dont see which servers settings I should use.

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: you should not. Fiddling with those files is a bad idea. Rather make the `mongod` available to your local machine and query the data, which is the intended way of remote access.

Comment: What do you mean? Open a mongod instance on my machine to open those files? This is exacly what i want to do.

Comment: You shouldn't run two instances on the same data. You should run a `mongo`-client...

Comment: thanks markus. let me explain my setup. I am using the twitter streaming api using the code here http://www.danielforsyth.me/analyzing-a-nhl-playoff-game-with-twitter/. Twitter data is in a json format so mongodb is an appropriate database. Problem is: the computer running the twitter python code is a remote one, and I would like to access the twitter data remotely. Actually I dont really care about the mongodb stuff, I just need to get the twitter data. What would you suggest here?

Comment: Using a freaking MongoDB client to get the freaking data out of the freaking MongoDB server... Like a web browser can access remote servers to get HTML data via the HTTP protocol, the `mongo` client  can get JSON from a remote `mongod` server via MongoDB's wire protocol. Simply connect to the existing server using an appropriate client, be it ` mongo`, the Python driver or whatever client you wish. Oh, and btw: Dropbox has a horrible latency. This setup will blow up as soon as you write serious data to it.

Comment: OK I understand. thanks again! Last question: do you mind telling me what is the syntax I should use to connect to the remote mongo server? I should use the IP address of the remote computer (which is a windows VM on google cloud)?

Comment: Don't know the Windows cloud (no Windows here, sorry), but IP address or hostname  and port is what you usually need. Please read [* Using the mongo shell*](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/mongo/) for details.

Comment: You definitely don't want to have your MongoDB `dbpath` in a folder sync'd by Dropbox. This can create easy scenarios for database corruption (particularly if you attempt to have multiple `mongod` servers accessing sync'd copies of your `dbpath`). You should instead use a [supported backup method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) for MongoDB or consider using a cloud-hosted database or database-as-a-service solution so you can access the data on the go (over a secure VPN / ssh tunnel).

Comment: It sounds like you've decided to use a remote Windows VM. You definitely don't want to expose direct access to this server over the internet (i.e. you should have firewall enabled and use a VPN or ssh tunnel to connect). For some general best practices see the [MongoDB Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the manual.